# how to automatically export mysql database in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

is it possible to automatically export mysql database in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PMA don't have any scheduler itself. use mysqldump + cron instead of.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to automatically export a database in PHPMyAdmin

But there you have to Run a Cron job script and set this script on the server and after that schedule a specific date and time to export a database.

Test to Verify if the Script is Working Correctly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35187605)